# Internet Explorer context menu context bits

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, contextmenu

I am trying to add two new entries to the context menu, one for images and one for anchors. I am using  0x2 for images 0x20 for anchors they are displayed correctly but when there is an image with a link only the image link is showed they do different things so i would like both items to show up?

Comment: What bits are being specified in that scenario?  How is your code checking the bits?  Can you show that code?

Comment: well i have two registry entries with 0x2 and 0x20 having different text i want both of them to show up for a image with a link. there is no code.

Answer (score 0):

@Remy - this is a windows registry setting used to extend the Context Menu in IE.

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\MenuExt\\`

@Hamza 
You'll need to change the 0x20 to 0x22 (the sum of 0x2 and 0x20) and then inspect the "external.menuArguments.event.srcElement" property in the script.  If it's an image, then use it's src property if it's an anchor scan it's child nodes for any image elements.

You could also just use 0x1 or 0x3F which represet "Default" and "All" respectively. Here are all of the values available -

1 = Default, 
2 = Images, 
4 = Controls, 
8 = Tables, 
16 = Text selection, 
32 = Anchor, 
63 = All

(8,Tables doesn't work at all AFAIK)